# php glob function and non-ascii characters

Tags: php, ascii, glob

I am using php glob() function to find matching files in a directory.

```
glob("*.txt");
```

It works for filenames with ascii characters e.g. sports.txt, frys.txt etc. However, it does not work with filenames that contain non-ascii character such as pénètre.txt.

Any thoughts?

Comment: as far as I know, PHP does not offer native Unicode support. PHP only supports a 256-character set.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run this code to my local computer

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.html") as $filename) {
  echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n<br>";
}
?>
```

and I included a file named pènétre as you wrote, but I got a clear output without any error:

```
cookie.html size 357 
pénètre.html size 7719
```

My PHP version is 1.6.2. Try to run this code as well and tell me if you experience any problem.

Comment: You are correct. However, the problem comes in this scenario glob("*.pénètre.html")  where * is placed before pénètre.html   and I am using windows.

Comment: I see. If you cannot use the wildchar glob("*.html") and you type any non-ascii character in the function, you have to escape those with \. Try glob("\\*.pénètre.html"), and if the filename is *.pénètre.html, it should work (I tried in my local machine, I have a Mac though).

Comment: I mean, * is an ascii character, but since it has a special meaning, you have to escape it as well. For example if your filename is ¢*.pénètre.html, your function will be glob("\¢\\*.pénètre.html")